# Role of $f$ Target Network in DDPG

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, actor-critic-methods, ddpg

I am trying to create a variant of DDPG in MATLAB that has no action-value $\langle Q \rangle$ net, but that instead works with networks $\langle V \rangle, \langle f \rangle, \langle r \rangle$, and also target networks $V^{+}$ and $f^{+}$ (but no $r^{+}$ or $Q^{+}$). Here, $V$ is the value function $V^{\mu} = Q^{\mu}(s, \mu(s))$, i.e., it is simply $Q^{\mu}(s, a)$ when $a$ is chosen to fit the policy $\mu$, $f$ is the state dynamics function and $r$ is the reward. Altogether, $Q^{\mu}(s_t, a_t) = r(s_t, a_t) \Delta t + V^{\mu}(s_{t+\Delta t})$, setting the discount factor $\gamma = 1$.  In the task given, I am instructed to train

- $\langle r\rangle$ based on minibatches drawn from a replay buffer, using a loss function that is half the square error $e^{r} = \langle r \rangle (s\_, a\_) - r\_$, where $s\_, a\_, r\_$ are from the buffer.
- $\langle f \rangle$ using a loss function that is half the square of $e^{f} = \langle V \rangle(\langle f \rangle (s\_, a\_)) - \langle V \rangle(s_{next}\_)$
- $\langle V \rangle$ by using an analogue to the Bellman error for $\langle Q \rangle$

What I do not see in all of this is the need for a target network $f^{+}$. The use of the target network $V^{+}$ arises because $e^f$ and $e^{V}$ admit two instances of the same network $V$–– thus, to simplify things, one can assign the first instance of $V$ to $\langle V \rangle$ and the other to the target $V^{+}$, before ultimately nudging the parameters of $V^{+}$ towards those of $\langle V \rangle.$ But role does $f^{+}$ play?